# Copy a file to 2 output directory using csproj dotnetcore

Tags: .net-core, csproj

I want to copy a file to 2 output directories using `csproj` dotnetcore. I use this code, but it just copies the file to the 2nd directory.

```
<Content Include="lock_screen_linux.desktop" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest">
        <LinuxPath>/usr/share/applications/lock_screen_linux.desktop</LinuxPath>
        <LinuxPath>/etc/xdg/autostart/lock_screen_linux.desktop</LinuxPath>
    </Content>
```

Comment: Do you want the file to be in the output directory (e.g. `bin/Debug/net6.0/etc/xdg/...`) or copied to the absolute location? how do you want it to behave when publishing to a directory (`dotnet publish -o ../output` )?

Comment: It is absolute location.I use `dotnet msbuild .\lock_screen_linux.csproj /t:CreateRpm /p:TargetFramework=netcoreapp3.1 /p:RuntimeIdentifier=linux-x64 /p:Configuration=Release` command publish the software.I want the file can be created in 2 directories :`/usr/share/applications/` and `/etc/xdg/autostart/`